# Kibana OIDC Okta Integration redirecting straight to ${KIBANA_URL}/auth/openid/login with 401

Tags: kibana, openid-connect, elasticsearch-opendistro

I'm trying to integrate open distro ELK with OpenID Connect by following the guide here (https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security/configuration/openid-connect/#kibana-single-sign-on), specifically by updating the kibana.yml and config.yml files as shown.

The behavior I'm seeing is:

1. Visit ${KIBANA_URL}
2. Get redirected straight to ${KIBANA_URL}/auth/openid/login with 401

I'm checking the network requests, and I'm not sure why it's not redirecting to the IDP (Okta) first. What should I check next?